# Possible to limit an SSL certificate holder to issuing redirects?

Tags: tls, network, digital-signature

Is it possible to issue an SSL certificate that limits the certificate holder to issuing https redirects?  Or more generally, limiting the holder to issuing specified data through the secure pipe, once it has been established?

I would like to let edge nodes issue https redirects.  It is impracticable to lock down the edge nodes to the extent needed.  Normally, to issue https redirects I would use a normal ssl certificate, however that would allow the edge node to return any data it wished, which is a huge security hole.  This is a problem with certifying a pipe, not the data that goes through the pipe.

Any recommendations, or secure alternatives, would be welcome.

Thanks in advance, Max

Comment: Note:  I assume that for redirect-only https certificates to exist there would have to be (1) an X509 extension that expresses the restriction and (2) browsers would have to support the extension.  There does not seem to be a nice list of supported X509 extensions, that is either short enough to read through manually or searchable.  If you know of one, please let me know!

Comment: There is no such extension and no such standard. Limit on HTTPS redirection is configured on client only and does not rely on connection type (HTTP or HTTPS). Look at this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10895406/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-http-redirections-allowed-by-all-major-browsers

Comment: This sounds a lot like an XY problem. Why do you want to issue a redirect-only certificate?

Comment: @MechMK1 Because the server that terminates the https connection cannot be fully trusted.

Comment: @MaxMurphy If the server that terminates the HTTPS connection cannot be fully trusted, your architecture is broken. This *still* sounds like an XY problem even with that clarification. Why is the server untrusted? What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: Reliable, tamper resistant infrastructure that works even when offline, or when a region or locality is disconnected from the rest of the internet.  Tamper resistant, in browsers, basically means that sites need to come up with a padlock.  This does NOT mean that the sites have an ssl connection to the server, obviously.  Sites can be downloaded to local or regional archives and served from the caches.  Now, the challenge is seamless but tamperproof redirection to archives when direct access is not possible.  This needs a local or regional https redirect to the archive.

Comment: Regarding getting a padlock without an ssl connection, this is can be done with signed data such as SXG.  If you are served an SXG file and the origin signature checks out, Chromium and IE will display it just as if you were visiting https://$THE_ORIGIN.  This is super for archives (think archive.org, but with proof that the data was captured correctly and hasn't been tampered with) and for networking in locations with low quality internet access.

Answer (score 2):

## No, there is no way to do that.

There is no SSL/TLS standard to restrict usage as HTTP server to only issuing HTTP 301 responses.

Comment: What proof do you have?  What extensions have you checked?

Comment: @MaxMurphy This answer is correct. The HTTP protocol is separate to the TLS protocol. Once the TLS session has been created, the underlying data going through that session is completely agnostic and effectively opaque. Preventing such redirects at the TLS layer would require the protocol to inspect the underlying application-layer protocol. There is no such extension.

Comment: @MaxMurphy What do you expect me to do? Show you the entire source code of every browser there is, just to show that there is no check for some TLS extension?

Comment: The TLS protocol does not care about what is being encapsulated on it.

Comment: @ThoriumBR But a TLS certificate can hold certain extensions, which can be relevant to HTTP. It's not unthinkable that such an extension could exist - it just doesn't.

Comment: @MechMK1 - I'd like to know what you have checked and what you haven't.  For example, in X509 there is an extended key usage extension, but looking up the values currently supported in Chromium shows that there is no suitable value, so if there is  a solution to be found, it is not there.  To adapt Kennedy's quote, we do this not because it is easy, and uses the path most trodden, but because it is hard and delivers for those who have not been served well before.

Comment: If the basis of your answer is 30 years of being a sysadmin, you probably won't have probed into the odder corners of X509 that much, and probably won't have encountered this use case.  If on the other hand you design X509 extensions for a living I would trust your "this does not exist" more, but I would expect you to be able to back it up with which extensions are most relevant.  If there is some corner of X509 that supports this out of the box, great, but if it does not exist, we need to add it, but that of course takes a lot of time and effort and persuasion.

Comment: @ThoriumBR "The TLS protocol does not care about what is being encapsulated on it. " true, but that is an incomplete picture.  The browser looks both at the connection and the data, so it can set up a TLS connection, then look at the connection details and depending on those, handle different data in different ways.  This already happens in mainstream browsers.